# How do I follow a path other than the Atlas path?

Tags: no-mans-sky

At the very beginning of the game, I had a choice to follow Atlas or "explore on my own, and I chose Atlas. Did this look me in to the Atlas path?

Based on [this developer blog post](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/2016/08/update-1-03/), it sounds like there are two more paths. Am I going to have a chance to switch over to these? Is it too late based on that choice I made in the first few minutes of the game? If I want to restart and follow a different path, how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure of the answer but just exploring my first planet I have come across several crashed craft that offer the 'follow the path' option again.

Comment: I tried to answer this question but my searches to find out what the 3 paths even are, left me more confused. It seems no one really knows what the 3 paths are. Some say its trading, exploring or fighting. Others say finding the atlas, finding the center of the universe and an unknown(?) 3rd option. And another is possibly destroying/controlling the atlas or synthesis but I'm not sure if any of those are possible, or what synthesis is supposed to mean, since I haven't played for too long myself.

Comment: Random sidenote: "Atlus" is a game developer, known for e.g. Tactics Ogre. "Atlas" is the thing in the game (and also a book of maps, and a creature in Greek mythology who holds the entire world on his shoulders).

Answer (score 2):

There are three paths available to you: Explore Freely, Journey to the Center, or the Atlas Path. This is made clear when encountering a Space Anomaly, where you will be given the choice to be given a technology (helping you to **Explore Freely**), have a black hole marked on your map (aiding you in **Journeying to the Center**), or be directed to the nearest Atlas Station (pointing you down the **Atlas Path**).

To "follow" the other two paths, either explore whatever stars you like, or head directly for the center, making use of black hole jumps where you can.